# C# displaying questions from a string array/ comparing user input with answers from second array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, user-input, windows-forms-designer

I have been working on a Trivia Game application to delve into independent learning and recently transferred my Trivia Game from a Console Application to a Windows Form Application. I am having trouble now as I am running into problems with getting my Windows application to do what I want.

Basic functionality of my program thus far:

1. I have a label that I want to display questions one at a time from my array.
2. I have a textbox that the user enters their answer into and I want that textbox to be compared with the answers array and determine whether the user is correct or incorrect.

I am able to get the first question displayed and the user's answer determined correct/incorrect working fine, though after the SECOND question is displayed in `lblquestion`, it determines the answer incorrect before an answer is even given and I can't figure it out. I have tried doing research online at dotnetpearls.com and other sites and read up on arrays and do while loops but still couldn't seem to find a way to make this work.

Here is my code that I have been working with so far:

```
public partial class frmentertainment : Form
{
   string[] entertainmentanswers = { "1982", "PEARL HARBOR","ACTOR" };
   string[] entertainmentquestions = { "What year did President Eisenhower become relieved of Presidency?", "What U.S. base was bombed forcing the United States to become involved in World War II", "What was the profession of Abraham Lincolns' assassin?"};

   int correct = 0;
   int incorrect = 0;

   public frmentertainment()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnanswer.Enabled = false;
   }

   private void frmentertainment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      lblquestion.Text = ("Welcome! In this category of Trivia you will be quizzed on questions about movies, actors/actresses, television shows and more! Press 'Start Trivia' when you are ready");
      txtanswer.Visible = false;
   }
   //track correct and incorrect answers
   private void KeepScore()
   {
      lblcorrect.Text = "Correct: " + correct;
      lblincorrect.Text = "Incorrect: " + incorrect;
   }
   private string txtboxvalue = ""; 

   private void txtanswer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //making sure txt is entered into txtbox
      if (txtanswer.Text != txtboxvalue)
      {
         btnanswer.Enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
         btnanswer.Enabled = false;
      }
   }

   //not working yet
   private void AskQuestions()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < entertainmentquestions.Length; i++)
      {
         lblquestion.Text = entertainmentquestions[i];
      }
   }

   private void ResetPrompt()
   {
      lblquestion.Text = "";
      txtanswer.Text = "";
   }

   private void AnalyzeFirstQuestion()
   {
      //determine if answer is wrong/right
      if (txtanswer.Text == entertainmentanswers[0])
      {
         MessageBox.Show("You got this one right!", "Correct!");
         correct += 1;
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("You got this one wrong! the correct answer was " + entertainmentanswers[0]);
         incorrect += 1;
      }
   }

   private void AnalyzeSecondQuestion()
   {
      if (txtanswer.Text == entertainmentanswers[1])
      {
         MessageBox.Show("You got this one right!", "Correct!");
         correct += 1;
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("You got this one wrong! The correct answer was " + entertainmentanswers[1], "Wrong!");
         incorrect += 1;
      }
   }

   private void btnanswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //button pressed to submit answer
      AnalyzeFirstQuestion();
      KeepScore();
      ResetPrompt();
      lblquestion.Text = entertainmentquestions[1];
      AnalyzeSecondQuestion();
   }

   private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
      //begin trivia, clicking this begins the first question
      btnstart.Visible = false;
      lblquestion.Text = entertainmentquestions[0];
      txtanswer.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

Is there a way I can add a break or a pause after displaying the second question so my code waits for the user to enter and answer before it determines if it is correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is the index like Coneone already pointed out and the string checking(relative to upper or lower case).You can try this design(ofcourse perfection is still miles away and improvements may be in order),but roughly it does the job and you can just paste the code to a new WindowsForms project and try it out:

1)after creating a new project add a new class and name it Quiz and paste this there:

```
    public class Quiz
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        private bool isAnswered = false;
        public bool IsAnswered
        {
            get { return isAnswered; }
            set { isAnswered = value; }
        }

        public Quiz(string question,string answer)
        {
            Question = question;
            Answer = answer;
        }
    }
```

2)Then in your form paste this code(ofcourse you will have to add the buttons,labels and textbox and named them approprietly and set the events to their respective handler):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<int, Quiz> questions;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int position = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnanswer.Enabled = false;
            questions = new Dictionary<int, Quiz>()
            {
                {0,new Quiz("What year did President Eisenhower become relieved of Presidency?","1982")},
                {1,new Quiz("What U.S. base was bombed forcing the United States to become involved in World War II","PEARL HARBOR")},
                {2,new Quiz( "What was the profession of Abraham Lincolns' assassin?","ACTOR")},
            };
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblquestion.Text = ("Welcome! In this category of Trivia you will be quizzed on questions about movies, actors/actresses, television shows and more! Press 'Start Trivia' when you are ready");
            txtanswer.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void KeepScore()
        {
            lblcorrect.Text = "Correct: " + correct;
            lblincorrect.Text = "Incorrect: " + incorrect;
        }

        private void txtanswer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //textbox always return empty string but i placed this here
            //so no need to create a variable and let you know
            //about other options....
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtanswer.Text))
            {
                btnanswer.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnanswer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void ResetPrompt()
        {
            lblquestion.Text = "";
            txtanswer.Text = "";
        }

        private void AnalyzeQuestion()
        {
            if (string.Equals(txtanswer.Text, questions[position].Answer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You got this one right!", "Correct!");
                correct += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You got this one wrong! the correct answer was " + questions[position].Answer);
                incorrect += 1;
            }
        }

        private void btnanswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AnalyzeQuestion();
            KeepScore();
            ResetPrompt();

            if (questions.Values.All(b => b.IsAnswered == true))
            {
                ResetAll();
                return;
            }
            GetQuestion();
        }

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnstart.Enabled = false;
            GetQuestion();
        }

        private void GetQuestion()
        {
            position = rand.Next(0, 3);
            if (questions[position].IsAnswered != true)
            {
                questions[position].IsAnswered = true;
                lblquestion.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblquestion.Text = questions[position].Question;
                txtanswer.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                while (questions[position].IsAnswered == true)
                {
                    position = rand.Next(0, 3);
                }
                questions[position].IsAnswered = true;
                lblquestion.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblquestion.Text = questions[position].Question;
                txtanswer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ResetAll()
        {
            txtanswer.Enabled = false;
            btnanswer.Enabled = false;
            position = 0;
            foreach (var item in questions.Values)
            {
                item.IsAnswered = false;
            }
            lblquestion.Text = "Game Over!!!...Please Press Start to Play Again.";
            btnstart.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you! I also enjoyed stepping through the code to really see how it worked, good learning experience too :)

Comment: OK, I have last question about this. Is it possible for me to populate a dictionary based on user input? Basically, can I do the same thing only reverse? I have tried by implementing two text boxes and am able to populate the Dictionary with a single "Question","Answer" key/value pair but can not do more than one key/value pair...

Comment: of course you can,in this example the int is for "getting" the right question,so with this dictionary you add 2 textboxes and a button and on the click handler you make some validation like checking if both textboxes are not empty and then do questions.Add(questions.Count, new Quiz(txtQuestion.Text, txtanswer.Text));.So you enter the question on txtQuestion and answer on txtAnswer and then click the button and it will be added to the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! I had to change a couple things around with the positioning logic to get it to work the way I had it set up but everything is working great now! Thank you for all your help, it is much appreciated @terrybozzio

Answer (score 2):

You can just keep track of the actual question through an integer variable.
Then you just need to rewrite the answer button clicl listener to this:

```
int count = 0;
private void AnalyzeQuestion(int x)
{

    if (txtanswer.Text == entertainmentanswers[x])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You got this one right!", "Correct!");
        correct += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You got this one wrong! The correct answer was " + entertainmentanswers[x], "Wrong!");
        incorrect += 1;
    }
}
private void btnanswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button pressed to submit answer
    AnalyzeQuestion(count);
    count++;
    KeepScore();
    ResetPrompt();
    lblquestion.Text = entertainmentquestions[count];
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but you'd likely be better off saving the users a headache and use String.Equals with an insensitive case comparison  and trimming off spaces when checking the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going with the latter example but I appreciate any answer as a different viewpoint and opportunity to learn something new!